# Latex error: "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char Ṕ (U+1E54)"

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

"! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char Ṕ (U+1E54)"

Does anyone know me explain what this error means and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{apalikept}

\pagestyle{empty}

\parindent=15mm

\geometry{paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,
textwidth=150mm,textheight=210mm,
top=35mm,bottom=25mm,
left=40mm,right=25mm}

\linespread{1.6}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[section]
\newtheorem{teo}[satz]{Teorema}
\newtheorem{coro}[satz]{Corolário}
\newtheorem{prop}[satz]{Proposição}
\newtheorem{lema}[satz]{Lema}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{df}[satz]{Definição}
\newtheorem{obs}[satz]{Observação}
\newtheorem{ex}[satz]{Exemplo}
\newtheorem{conv}[satz]{Convenção}

\newcommand{\tq}{\hspace{0.5mm}\mid\hspace{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\e}{\quad\mathrm{e}\quad}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\V}{\mathrm{Vol}}
\newcommand{\me}{m_{\ast}}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item Sejam $E_{1}, \dots, E_{n}, \dots$ conjuntos mensuráveis e 
considere $E = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_{j}$. Dado $\epsilon>0$, para 
cada $j$ escolhamos um aberto $O_{j}$ com $E_{j} \subset O_{j}$ e 
$\me(O_{j} - E_{j}) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2^{j}}$. Temos que $O = 
\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}O_{j}$ é aberto, $E \subset O$ e $O-E \subset 
\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}(O_{j} - E_{j})$. Ṕelas propriedades (i) e (ii) da 
proposição \hyperlink{2}{1.1.5}, temos
$$\me(O-E) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}\me(O_{j} - E_{j}) \leq \epsilon.$$
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please can you add your complete and compilable code?

Comment: Done! The problem is in the line "Ṕelas propriedades (i) e (ii) da 
proposição \hyperlink{2}{1.1.5}, temos"

Comment: Can you try to compile with LuaLaTeX (I work well for me)? After can you put this code `\[\me(O-E) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}\me(O_{j} - E_{j}) \leq \epsilon.\]` instead of `$$...$$`?

Comment: is Ṕ a common letter in Brazilian Portuguese? (we were wondering if this should be defined by default, but don't recall this coming up before, and practically we can't pre-define every possible Unicode accent combination,so need to make a judgement on which letters to pre-define and which leave for the user to define if needed)

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: It is unnecessary to load a package more than once, you can remove the second `\usepackage{graphicx}` from your preamble.

Comment: This is just a problem caused by a typo.

Comment: As Joseph spoke, it was a typo that I didn't understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only show a small fraction of the error message. The full error message shows more context and how to fix it:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Ṕ (U+1E54)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.73 \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}(O_{j} - E_{j})$. Ṕ
                                              elas propriedades (i) e (ii) da
? h
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
?
```

As suggested, adding

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E54}{\'{P}}
```

to the end of your preamble fixes the problem.